# Specify output names on multiple files with curl using ranges

Tags: php, linux, curl, ssh

I am trying to download a few hundred URL's and specify the output name for each, the only difference is an ID in the URL, such as `..something/1/something..`, `..something/3/something..`, `..something/4/something..` etc.

I can use `-o filename.zip` but it will overwrite for each of the range of files, I am currently using:

```
curl -o file.zip http://example.com/something/[1-500]/something/example/foo/bar/comma/zip
```

How can I output as this:?

file1.zip, file3.zip, file4.zip, ..etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple loop in your shell would do the trick e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 500`; do
    curl -o file$i.zip http://example.com/something/$i/something/example/foo/bar/comma/zip
done
```